# PostgreSQL C function: libpq doesn't link?

Tags: postgresql, c

I want to write a C function for PostgreSQL. For this function I will need to query some data using libpq, so I started by writing a dummy function to test this part:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <postgres.h>
#include <fmgr.h>
#include <funcapi.h>
#include <executor/executor.h>

#include "test.h"

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(getAnnotation);
Datum getAnnotation(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
    // Connection to the database
    PGconn *conn = PQsetdbLogin("localhost",
                         "5432",
                         "",
                         "",
                         "postgres",
                         "postgres",
                         "password");

    // Databases names
    PGresult *res = PQexec (conn, "SELECT user FROM activity LIMIT 1;");
    VarChar* i = PQgetvalue(res, 0, 0);
    PG_RETURN_VARCHAR_P(i);
}
```

It is just supposed to return the first column of the first line of one of my tables. Pretty simple right ? Well it doesn't work.

When I try to use it within psql, it says :

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/local/lib/postgresql/test.so": Error relocating /usr/local/lib/postgresql/test.so: PQexec: symbol not found
```

The weird part is that both `PQsetdbLogin` and `PQexec` are in the `libpq-fe.h` file, but only the second one causes an error. If I comment the `PQexec` line, then `PQsetdbLogin` raises an error as well.

Here is the Makefile I use to build the code:

```
PG_CPPFLAGS = -I$(libpq_srcdir)
LDFLAGS_INTERNAL = -L$(libdir)
SHLIB_LINK_INTERNAL = $(libpq)
SHLIB_PREREQS = submake-libpq

EXTENSION = test
DATA = test--0.1.sql
MODULES = test

# REGRESS = ... # Script for tests

PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

As you can see, I linked libpq therem so everything should work... But it doesn't and I don't know why.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6 in a docker container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to link with external libraries, you need `SHLIB_LINK`, but that only works if you use `MODULE_big` instead of `MODULES`.

A working `Makefile` would be

```
PG_CPPFLAGS = -I$(libpq_srcdir)
SHLIB_LINK = $(libpq)

EXTENSION = test
DATA = test--0.1.sql
MODULE_big = test
OBJS = test.o

PG_CONFIG = pg_config
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
```

But there are other problems with your function:

- `VarChar` is a `varlena`, but `PQgetvalue` returns a `char *`.

  You'd have to convert the value to a `varlena` with code similar to this:

  ```c
  VarChar *result;
  char *c = PQgetvalue(res, 0, 0);
  result = (VarChar *) palloc(strlen(c) + VARHDRSZ);
  strncpy(VARDATA(result), c, strlen(c));
  SET_VARSIZE(result, strlen(c) + VARHDRSZ);
  ```
- It is usually the wrong idea to write client code in a server function.

  If all you need is to run a query inside the current session, use the [Server Programming Interface](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spi.html).
- I guess your function is only sample code, but you need to close the connection before the backend terminates, else you have a connection leak.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the makefile works ! I will also take a look at the Server Programming Interface. I never heard of it before but it looks to be a better solution for what I want to do.